# Can't write on plist file after deploying on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, simulator

Dear all.
I am facing a problem.
I can read and write on plist while working on simulator of xcode. but when I deploy the app in iPhone, i can't write on plists.

I have created a sample project having 2 button on it. By one button, I can display the text from plist. By second button, I try to write on that plist. But the writing doesn't happen. The app doesn't crash while clicking on the second button. I can't understand the problem in my code.

```
/*code is given below*/
-(void)writePlist:(NSString *)fname withArray:(NSMutableArray *) myArray
{
   NSString * path = nil;
   path = [(NSString *) [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fname];
   [myArray writeToFile:path atomically:NO];   
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code, it should work.  How do you know it's not being saved?  Is writeToFile returning NO?  Can you post the code that shows how you call this function?

Comment: What objects are in the array?  If they are not "property list objects" (which are NSString, NSData, NSArray and NSDictionary) you cannot use that method to save the file.

Comment: @zpasternack: [self writePlist:@"my.plist" withArray:myArray];

Comment: @Simon: myArray is NSMutableArray type and my.plist file is in Resource folder.

Comment: Yes, but what type of objects are _in_ the array?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `myArray` variable contains non-serializable object values (probably custom objects or something like that).

Comment: myArray is type of NSMutableArray. Is it a problem?

Comment: the object in array. What type of objects are in there?

Answer (score 0):

Does the directory you are trying to write to exist? You may want to verify its existence (and create it if it isn't already there) before trying to write a file into it.

Comment: hi. we have checked and the directory exists. directory is not a problem in here. thanks for your comment.